# Understanding readResolve method

Tags: java, serialization

I'm reading J.Bloch's effective Java and now I'm the section about `readResolve` method.

I'm experimenting with `readResolve` method and wrote the following program:

```
public static void main(String args[]) throws FileNotFoundException, IOException, ClassNotFoundException{
try(FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(file);
            ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(fis)){
        ResDerived rr = (ResDerived) ois.readObject();
        System.out.println(rr);
    }
}
```

Base class containing `readResove`:

```
public static class ReadResolved implements Serializable{

    private transient String def = "default";

    public ReadResolved(String def) {
        this.def = def;
    }

    private void writeObject(ObjectOutputStream ous) throws ClassNotFoundException, IOException{
        ous.defaultWriteObject();
        ous.writeObject(def);
    }

    private void readObject(ObjectInputStream ois) throws ClassNotFoundException, IOException{
        ois.defaultReadObject();
        def = (String) ois.readObject();
    }

    public Object readResolve(){
        def = "default";
        return this;
    }
}
```

Derived class:

```
public static class ResDerived extends ReadResolved{

    public ResDerived(String def) {
        super(def);
    }

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

}
```

Runnning the program produce the instance of ResDerived containing the ReadResolver with the `def = default`. J.Bloch said that

> If a  readResolve  method is protected or public and a subclass does
>   not override  it, deserializing a serialized subclass instance will
>   produce a superclass instance, which is likely to cause a 
>   `ClassCastException` .

Why does my program run fine? Why doesn't produce `ClassCastException` as it's supposed to?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because you're returning `this`, instead of a replacement object, and `this` is already of the correct type, by definition.

Normally when you use this method it would be in conjunction with a `writeReplace()` method, that would return a different object to be serialized, and whose obligation would be to have a `readResolve()` method that returned an object of the original type. You're not doing that here, so what you're really doing is misusing `readResolve()` in a rather pointless way, that could just as well be accomplished within a custom `readObject()` method, without raising arcane questions like this.